# EzPublish legacy - Fetching Meta tags

Tags: fetch, meta-tags, legacy, ezpublish

So i have my main meta tags e.g keywords, description..

But on specific sites i want to add a class named metatags where i can insert individual meta tags for the site.

Now my problem is that i don't know how to fetch those. I need a fallback so when i don't have my metatags class, the standard metatags will be used. But when i have my metatags class added they should be shown as well.

I tried it like this and wrote into the  section on the pagelayout.tpl :

```
{let node_metas=fetch(content, node, hash(node_id, $module_result.node_id))}
{if eq( $node_metas.object.data_map.meta_description.content,""}
<meta name="description" content="{$site.meta.description|wash}">
{else}
<meta name="description" content="{$node_metas.object.data_map.meta_description.content|wash}">
{/if}
{if eq( $node_metas.object.data_map.meta_keys.content,""}
<meta name="keywords" content="{$site.meta.keywords|wash}">
{else}
<meta name="keywords" content="{$node_metas.object.data_map.meta_keys.content|wash}">
{/if}
{/let}
```

Does anyone have an idea why it's not working? I'm still new to ezpublish so i'm thankful for any help !

Answer (score 0):

try this in your page_head.tpl

```
{def $currentNode = fetch( 'content', 'node', hash( 'node_id', ezpagedata().node_id ))}

{if $currentNode.data_map.meta_tag_description.has_content}
    <meta name="description" content="{$currentNode.data_map.meta_tag_description.content|wash}">
{else}
    <meta name="description" content="{$site.meta.description|wash}">
{/if}
```